# wedge product and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-topology

[image]

I don't really know what $[\phi_i(v_j)]$ really is. As far as I understand, $\phi_i$ is a linear transformation - a matrix; and $v_j$ is the column vector it eats. So $[\phi_i(v_j)]$ spit out column vectors, rather than $k \times k$ real matrix as the problem stated.

Again, thanks for your help~

Comment: $V^*$ is common notation for the dual of the vector space $V$, defined as the vector space of all linear functionals on $V$. More explicitly, a $\phi \in V^*$ is a linear map $V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. This is why $\phi_i(v_j)$ is a single number for each $1 \leq i,j \leq k$, and so $(\phi_i(v_j))_{ij}$ really is a $k \times k$ matrix.

Comment: I don't think your question has much to do with differential topology. This question is just about multilinear algebra, or perhaps exterior algebra. To prove the given statement, I would need to know two things, (1.) how do you define the wedge product (2.) how do you define the determinant. Once those are clarified it's an identity.

Comment: Thanks @ABlumenthal. So thinking of $\phi \in V^*$ as a linear map, $\phi_i$ is the $i$th column vector of the matrix $\phi$, and $v_j$ picks the $j$th row?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook It is Ex 4.2.3 on GP. Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: @Jellyfish what is GP and where can I find it? Sorry if this is obvious to everyone else...

Comment: @Jellyfish It won't matter which corresponds to columns because $\det A = \det A^T$.

Comment: Oh Sorry my fault @JamesS.Cook. Someone corrected me, but I still forgot to address it fully when I talk in the comment. It is Guillemin and Pollack's Differential Topology, the exercise is on Page 160.

Comment: @Jellyfish well, I'll leave it to the others here then since I sadly do not possess that text. It is on my wish list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dual space $V^\star$ contains linear maps **into the reals** $\mathbb R$ and so for each $i,j$ we obtain a real number. Them thinking of $i,j$ being indices in a table, this defines a matrix.