# Find $dr\wedge d\alpha \wedge d\beta$ in terms of $dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$.

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

\Let $$x=r\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$$
$$y=r\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$$
$$z=r\cos(\beta)$$
be the spherical coordinates. Find $dr\wedge d\alpha \wedge d\beta$ in terms of $dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$.

I have never seen a question like this so I'm a bit confused. Do I need to differentiate $x,y,z$ respectively to $r,\alpha,\beta$ ?

My first approach was $xdx=r\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)dx$ , $ydy=r\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)dy$ and $zdz=r\cos(\beta)dz$.

$(xyz) dx\wedge dy\wedge dz=(r^3\cos(\alpha)\cos^2(\beta)\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta))dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$.

Is this a right path to follow or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Can you see how to prove that $dx \wedge dy \wedge dz = \pm r^2 \sin(\beta)\, dr \wedge d\alpha \wedge d \beta$ (too lazy to figure out the sign)? From here, you just have to divide both sides, and then express $r$ and $\beta$ in terms of $x,y,z$.

Comment: Sadly no. This is the first time that I’ve seen this. How did you get $dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ to that?

Comment: Use the fact that $dx = \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r} dr + \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \alpha} d \alpha + \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \beta} d \beta$. And likewise for $y$ and $z$. Then, simply use the familiar properties of wedge products (being careful with $-$ signs).

Comment: Are you sure the expressions are correct? You should have $x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2$, but you get $x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2(\cos^2 \alpha \sin^2 \beta + \sin^2 \alpha \cos^2 \beta + \cos^2 \beta)$.

Comment: Thanks, I edited $y=rsin(\alpha)cos(\beta)$ to $y=rsin(\alpha)sin(\beta)$. Sorry about that, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will compute the expression in opposite direction. i.e. attempt to express  $dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$ in terms of $dr\wedge d\alpha \wedge d\beta$ first.

$$\begin{align} & dx \wedge dy \wedge dz\\
= & \frac1z dx \wedge dy \wedge zdz\\
= & \frac1z dx \wedge dy \wedge (xdx + ydy + zdz)\\
= &\frac{1}{2z} dx\wedge dy \wedge d(x^2+y^2+z^2)\\
= & \frac{1}{2z} dx\wedge dy \wedge dr^2\\
= & \frac{r}{z} d(x \wedge dy \wedge dr\\
= & \frac{1}{\cos\beta}d(r\cos\alpha\sin\beta) \wedge d(r\sin\alpha\sin\beta) \wedge dr\\
=  &\frac{r^2}{\cos\beta}d(\cos\alpha\sin\beta)\wedge d(\sin\alpha\sin\beta) \wedge dr
\end{align}$$
Notice 
$$\begin{align} & d(\cos\alpha\sin\beta)\wedge d(\sin\alpha\sin\beta)\\
= & (-\sin\alpha\sin\beta d\alpha + \cos\alpha\cos\beta d\beta)
\wedge (\cos\alpha\sin\beta d\alpha + \sin\alpha\cos\beta d\beta)\\
= & \sin\beta\cos\beta( -\sin^2\alpha^2 - \cos^2\alpha) d\alpha\wedge d\beta)\\
= & -\sin\beta\cos\beta d\alpha\wedge d\beta\end{align}$$

We obtain

$$dx \wedge dy \wedge dz = -\frac{r^2}{\cos\beta}\sin\beta\cos\beta d\alpha\wedge d\beta\wedge dr
= - r^2 \sin\beta dr\wedge d\alpha \wedge d\beta$$

From this, it is easy to see
$$dr \wedge d\alpha \wedge d\beta = -\frac{dx \wedge dy \wedge dz}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x^2+y^2)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: the functions $x,y,z$ depend on $r,\alpha,\beta$, so their differentials are
\begin{align*}
dx &= \cos \alpha \sin \beta dr-r\sin\alpha\sin \beta d\alpha+ r\cos \alpha \cos \beta d\beta, \\
dy &= \sin \alpha \sin \beta dr+r\cos \alpha \sin \beta d\alpha + r\sin \alpha \cos \beta d\beta, \\
dz &= \cos \beta dr - r\sin \beta d\beta.
\end{align*}
You can write this as a system:
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
dx \\
dy \\
dz
\end{matrix}
\right)
= \left(
\begin{matrix}
\cos \alpha \sin \beta & -r \sin \alpha \sin \beta & r\cos \alpha \cos \beta \\
\sin \alpha \sin \beta & r\cos \alpha \sin \beta & r\sin \alpha \cos \beta \\
\cos \beta & 0 & -r\sin \beta
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
dr \\
d\alpha \\
d\beta
\end{matrix}
\right).
$$
Now you need to invert this system. This way you obtain explicit expressions of $dr,d\alpha$, and $d\beta$. Assume you find $dr = adx+bdy+cdz, d\alpha = a'dx+b'dy+c'dz$, then the rule to compute $dr \wedge d\alpha$ is 
$$dr \wedge d\alpha = (ab'-a'b)dx\wedge dy+(ac'-a'c)dx \wedge dz + (bc'-b'c)dy \wedge dz.$$
From here you can compute $dr \wedge d\alpha \wedge d\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to compute the differentials $dy^i = \sum_j {\partial y^i\over\partial x^j}\,dx^j$, that is, $$dx = \cos\alpha\sin\beta\,dr - r\sin\alpha\sin\beta\,d\alpha + r\cos\alpha\cos\beta\,d\beta$$ and so on. You could then grind through computing all of those wedge products term by term, but a simpler approach is to relate the wedge product to a determinant, as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/425819/265466). In this case, we have $$dr\wedge d\alpha\wedge d\beta = {\partial(r,\alpha,\beta)\over\partial(x,y,z)}\,dx\wedge dy\wedge dz,$$ so the problem reduces to computing the Jacobian determinant of the coordinate transformation.  This is the analog of the change-of-variables formula for integrals that you probably learned in a previous calculus course. Instead of inverting the coordinate transformation you’ve been given, it’s easier to compute its Jacobian determinant and invert that, then rewrite it in terms of $x$, $y$ and $z$ if needed.

In fact, what you’re being asked to do is to compute the pullback of the volume form on $\mathbb R^3$ under the map $f:(r,\alpha,\beta)\mapsto(r\cos\alpha\sin\beta,r\sin\alpha\sin\beta,r\cos\beta)$. There’s a somewhat complex explicit general formula for the pullback of a $k$-form, but for an $n$-form in $\mathbb R^n$ it reduces to a single Jacobian as above.